# dynamically allocating memory to struct when reading from file in C++

Tags: c++, struct

I have a struct

```
typedef struct student
{
    char name[10];
    int age;
    vector<int> grades;
} student_t;
```

And I'm writing its contents to a binary file.

I write at different times and have many data on file that are written from this struct.

Now, I want to read ALL the data that is there on the binary file on to the struct.
I'm not sure how I can allocate memory(dynamically) to the struct so that the struct can accommodate all the data on to the struct.

Can you please help me out with this.

Code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;


typedef struct student
{
    char name[10];
    int age;
    vector<int> grades;
}student_t;

int main()
{
    student_t apprentice[3];
    strcpy(apprentice[0].name, "john");
    apprentice[0].age = 21;
    apprentice[0].grades.push_back(1);
    apprentice[0].grades.push_back(3);
    apprentice[0].grades.push_back(5);

    strcpy(apprentice[1].name, "jerry");
    apprentice[1].age = 22;
    apprentice[1].grades.push_back(2);
    apprentice[1].grades.push_back(4);
    apprentice[1].grades.push_back(6);

    strcpy(apprentice[2].name, "jimmy");
    apprentice[2].age = 23;
    apprentice[2].grades.push_back(8);
    apprentice[2].grades.push_back(9);
    apprentice[2].grades.push_back(10);

    // Serializing struct to student.data
    ofstream output_file("students.data", ios::binary);
    output_file.write((char*)&apprentice, sizeof(apprentice));
    output_file.close();

    // Reading from it
    ifstream input_file("students.data", ios::binary);
    student_t master;

    input_file.seekg (0, ios::end);
    cout << input_file.tellg();

    std::vector<student_t> s;

    // input_file.read((char*)s, sizeof(s)); - dint work

    /*input_file >> std::noskipws;
    std::copy(istream_iterator(input_file), istream_iterator(), std::back_inserter(s));*/

    while(input_file >> master) // throws error
    {
        s.push_back(master);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. `vector` already handles dynamic allocation. Do you mean that you have a container full of `student_t` that you want to dynamically allocate?

Comment: say i write a struct array say student_t[5] to the binary and do it 4 times. I want to pull data from the binary file onto the struct. But I will not know who many such struct has been written(as the the user can write any number of such struct array). I would like to know a way to pull dynamic data onto struct.

Comment: You have to record how many structs were written.

Comment: Why use vector in one place, but (1) not use vector to get multiple students and (2) use a c-style string instead of `std::string`? I mean, I get ignoring advanced features in order to learn about low-level stuff, but half using them seems silly.

Comment: If your concern is about the binary file, you can test for EOF (=End Of File). If it is about the C++ part of the code, you should use a `vector<student_t>`. Vectors already handle the dynamic allocation and you can call `.size()` on them.

Comment: @alestanis - i was just working on dynamically reading part. so, dint pay much attention to the rest. And this is a sample code that im trying which i took it from net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a `vector<student_t>` instead of old-style arrays. It will handle dynamic allocation (use `push_back()` to add items) and you can get its size with the `size()` method.

**EDIT:**
For the file reading you can do something like this:

```
ifstream myfile;
myfile.open(file_name);
if (myfile.is_open()) {
    while (myfile) {
        string s;
        getline(myfile, s);
        // Do something with the line
        // Push information into students vector
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add the binary options too.

For the `name` inside your `student_t` struct, it would be much easier to declare it as a `string`. That way, you wouldn't have to use `strcpy` and the like and you could just type `mystudent.name = "jimmy"`

Comment: I tried doing this
    while(input_file >> master)
    {
        s.push_back(master);
    }
but im getting error in the while part. Can you please help me out.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to add the code you just tried? Without looking at the code it's very difficult to help.

Comment: I'm trying it out now. I still have some issues with it.

Comment: Finally got it working. Looped till EOF, read file into struct and added pushed the struct into a vector.

Comment: Good! Don't forget to accept an answer if you solved your problem with our help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to invent a file format for this. At the beginning of the file you will be storing a so called "header", which contains information about the data contained in it. For example:

```
2 13 <DATA> 8 <DATA>
```

The first number (2) gives the amount of structs stored in the file. Then data blocks follow. Each data block begins with a number that specifies the size of the `grades` vector (13 for the first struct, 8 for the second).

In this case, you read an int from the beginning of the file. Now you know the file has 2 structs saved in it. Then, you read the next int, 13 in this case. That tells you you need a vector with a capacity of 13. You can create one, and then read all your values. You will know when to stop since you know how much data you have in this struct: 10 chars (name), 1 int (age), 13 ints (grades). After you have read all that, then you know that the next int will be part of the next struct in the file. It will be the number 8, which tells you that the next struct needs a vector of capacity 8.

Etc, etc, until you finished reading everything.

Note that this method of binary file I/O is not portable. There are two reasons for this. First, the size of int can differ between platforms. Second, the way an int (and other data bigger than a single byte) are stored in binary form can differ too, even if they have the same size (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness for an explanation.) But if you don't intend your program and the files it generates to be portable anyway, then the method I described above will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward approach is to unpackage the vector so that what you write to the file is not a vector but rather an array of ints along with the number of ints in the array.

So the first pass would be to write the first part that has a standard, unchanging structure, then a number that indicates the number of ints that will follow and then finally iterate over the vector writing the ints to the file.

Then when you read the file, you would create the struct with an empty vector, read the first part that is structured and unchanging into the struct, then read the number of ints to be placed in the vector, and then read that number of ints from the file.  As you read the ints from the file you would add them to the vector in the struct.

Comment: Actually I dont have any issues pulling data into the vector. If i knew i want to pull 3 sets of struct data then i can allocate it as student_t s[3]. But here i dont if it will be 3(it can be any arbitrary value based on the file contents). I'm not sure how to do it. Can you pl help me with this.

Comment: It sounds like you either want dynamic arrays, like `student_t* s = new student_t[num_structs];` or a `vector` of your struct like `std::vector<student_t> s;`.

Comment: @user1420351, you will need to use one of the collection classes such as vector to dynamically add copies of structs read from the file.  Or you could do as Geoff suggests with the new however to do that you would need to know how many are in the file so probably the collection such as vector would be much preferable.